# Android arabic Ebook App development

Tags: android

I have a pdf of a arabic book which i have to convert it to an app. with all feature like index of chapters, Copy and save notes from the page.

at **first** i thought of developing each page of the book in a layout and retriving content from a Sqlite DB.(*Bad idea*)

**second**, I did research and found could make html pages and save it in asset folder and access them for every index click. it worked well for sometime. but then turned out the html pages were not reponsive on smaller screen size. as arabic texts startd all shaking(lets just say was not printing on screen as i wanted).

**Third**, at last i decided to use pdf instead of html pages. but there are lot of drawbacks with that.Like, no default pdf reader in android. will have to use 3rd party app for that, no responsiveness of pages on smaller screens.

i would be very greatefull if anyone could guide me in correct way in making ebooks app. i searched on internet though about how does ebook app works and all but no help.

(**NOTE:** it has arabic text too)

Comment: may i know y downvote here?

Comment: did u find the way ?